# Is it possible to view UTF-8 Characters in DOS programs

Tags: text, dos, arabic, codepages

i am using [Hiew32](http://www.hiew.ru/) to find some Arabic sentences inside an EXE file

Before launching Hiew32.exe i tried with Lucida Console font and :

```
chcp 65001
```

But the result is the same; is there a method to view UTF-8 chars in DOS mode ?

Comment: Wow.  DOS.  Didn't realize anyone used that any more.  Good luck.

Comment: You mean DOS, or cmd.exe within windows?

Comment: This has already been answered:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388490/unicode-characters-in-windows-command-line-how/388500#388500

Comment: @RobSedgwick : did not work for me, so I have opened another post, thank you in advance

Comment: @mrwaim: of course cmd shell; i wrote DOS because i remeber the old holy DOS from Win 3.11 days

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using Hiew32 > file.txt, and open the file in notepad.

Or, consider using powershell.exe and start the command from there.

Powershell_ise.exe will have even better Arabic support